# Widget is not appearing in widget laucher section

Tags: android, widget, launcher, android-appwidget

I have created a widget from scratch, and it works, but it doesn't appear in the widget section of Android 4.0+ launchers.

What must I change to ensure the widget appears in that launcher section?

Comment: Does your app have an Activity and UI that can be opened otherwise?

Comment: Nope, on gingerbread i can lauch my widget because i juste have to press 3 sec desktop and widget menu pop up. It's a simple clock widget
[link]https://github.com/Pdroid/com.pdroidandroid.simpleclocknume/tree/expe1[/link] @Reghav Sood